# Bootstrap Column Shifting on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am writing kind of a library management webpage in which i want to display a book collection.

```html
<div class="panel-body">
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="width: auto;">
    <div style="position: relative; display:inline-block;"><img src="https://cdn.pastemagazine.com/www/system/images/photo_albums/hobbit-book-covers/large/photo_5653_0-7.jpg?1384968217" style="width:auto;max-height:150px"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ezIB-cHDLA12OTFqRavb6V9jmtX1aQZ-LqLRQ2CMprFgRjDqPP4dbo_4VVC_aAJ3WA=w300" style=" position: absolute;bottom: -10px;right: -3px;width: 30px;height: 30px;">

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
   <div class="row">Der Hobbit
    </div>
    <div class="row">Tolkin, J.R.R
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="width: auto;">
    <div style="position: relative; display:inline-block;"><img src="https://cdn.pastemagazine.com/www/system/images/photo_albums/hobbit-book-covers/large/photo_5653_0-7.jpg?1384968217" style="width:auto;max-height:150px"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ezIB-cHDLA12OTFqRavb6V9jmtX1aQZ-LqLRQ2CMprFgRjDqPP4dbo_4VVC_aAJ3WA=w300" style=" position: absolute;bottom: -10px;right: -3px;width: 30px;height: 30px;">

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">Der Hobbit
    </div>
    <div class="row">Tolkin, J.R.R
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="width: auto;">
    <div style="position: relative; display:inline-block;"><img src="https://cdn.pastemagazine.com/www/system/images/photo_albums/hobbit-book-covers/large/photo_5653_0-7.jpg?1384968217" style="width:auto;max-height:150px"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ezIB-cHDLA12OTFqRavb6V9jmtX1aQZ-LqLRQ2CMprFgRjDqPP4dbo_4VVC_aAJ3WA=w300" style=" position: absolute;bottom: -10px;right: -3px;width: 30px;height: 30px;">

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">Der Hobbit
    </div>
    <div class="row">Tolkin, J.R.R
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

On a small screen the columns are shifting weirdly. This is the way I want it to display:
[image]

I think that I messed up with the column classes - can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: I think you should check the manual again. The texts are in rows without columns, so it will be missing padding. This will cause the miss alignment I guess?

Answer (score 0):

The picture and the text are not in the same element. They are in two different rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code for each text:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">Der Hobbit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">Tolkin, J.R.R</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It might be enough like: (depends on your needs)

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
    Der Hobbit<br>
    Tolkin, J.R.R
</div>
```

Or like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
    <div>Der Hobbit</div>
    <div>Tolkin, J.R.R</div>
</div>
```

[image: result]

Comment: I tried the first one but it does not make a difference: https://www.bootply.com/ptPl9lPLLr

Comment: I added screenshot of how it should render.. if you want the images indented. You can add margin-left to it.

Comment: Change "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" to "col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3". Or just remove all those divs. They are missing a parent row anyway.